# Enable or disable checkout payment method based on user group

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, payment-methods

I've two types of customer: normal and business.
Normals users can pay with `PayPal` and `Verified by Visa`.
Business users can pay with `Bank Transfer` only.
How can I do this?

Comment: Please go through the link
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132449/magento-2-how-to-disable-enable-payment-method-based-on-customer/181221#181221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this not a proper answer so don't bark at me, but this Module works fine with minor adjustments.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/paymentfilter-for-products-and-customer-groups.html

This is not my work, I have nothing to do with the Developer of this Module

Comment: I would second this. I haven't used the module lately, but it is a good module. Also, here is the github link for the module: https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter

Comment: Nice to know, this module adds a block with the payment methods to the customer group in Admin. (it took me a while to figure this out ;))

Answer (score 1):

You can try extension https://github.com/riconeitzel/PaymentFilter, I have used it before and works fine for me.